# предлагаю синонимизировать active-directory и activedirectory

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено, синонимы-меток

например, вот в [этом вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/439032/178576) автор использовал обе эти метки.

правда, затрудняюсь предложить, какая из них должна быть «канонической».

Answer (score 3, accepted):

каноническая: active-directory

синоним к ней: activedirectory

Comment: По мне, каноническая должна быть та, где слова отделены дефисом. [tag:active-directory]

Comment: Синоним добавлен

Answer (score 0):

каноническая: activedirectory

синоним к ней: active-directory